# Marketing Cloud All Subscriber List not creating record for customer with "spam" in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

We have a customer using a legitimate email address that contains "spam" as part of their name. No subscriber record is being created for this customer, and they are not receiving emails from us. Is there a way to check the options to see if this person is being filtered out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SFMC has a secret "[List Detective](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000335444&language=en_US)" process that auto-suppresses email addresses that are known or likely to flag you as a spammer. There isn't a way to programmatically get this list out; but you can create a data extract for all the '[not sent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313980&type=1)' emails in Automation Studio to see who got suppressed.

Comment: ...all of that, and you can talk to support for custom exclusions to that feature.